# Paring iOS app to Samsung TV as remote controller

Tags: ios, upnp, samsung-smart-tv, remote-control

I have been using Upnpx library to discover the TV using Upnp protocol.
What I have to do now is to pare my iOS app with the TV as a remote controller.
The first objectives are to take control of the sound volume, move the mouse cursor, browse through web-browsers, etc.

I have tried to google for **urn:samsung.com:device:RemoteControlReceiver1** specification but I had a hard time to find ***useful*** informations.

Has someone already done this before and could give me directions or the technical specification to control the TV from a remote app ?

Regards,

Comment: any progress making iOS app that controls Samsung TV (like remote controller)? I am looking for some APIs or SDKs that allows that http://stackoverflow.com/q/28307793/514181

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem? I need some help in same issue, any solution? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com). That way you will be able to sniff your network. Then try to duplicate the functionality in your app.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the people who will face the same issues.

I paired my iOS app to the samsung TV through TCP socket (I used GCDAsyncSocket to handle this) and using the great informations I found here :
http://sc0ty.pl/2012/02/samsung-tv-network-remote-control-protocol/