# Remote control Samsung TV from iOS app

Tags: ios, api, sdk, samsung-smart-tv, television

I wonder what are requirements for developing iOS app that can be used as a remote controller for Samsung TV.

It's obvious that the TV needs to be connected to the network and be equipped in SMART TV feature. I would like to know if it's possible without modifying the TV software/firmware.

I didn't find any information about public APIs or iOS SDK from Samsung that could handle communication. As far as I understand the SDKs available on Samsung developer website are for creating apps that can be installed on the TV. However, I noticed several "remote controller" application on the AppStore, but don't have access to Samsung TV to check if they are working. I guess they have to use some official solutions in order to pass AppStore Review process.

Perhaps if there is no official SDK, some kind of universal protocol of can be used to connect with the TV and remotely change channel or retrieve currently watched channel info.

Looking forward to get some hints from people experienced in that topic, as I never did anything connected with TVs. Also, if you have knowledge about remote controlling other brands TV - please let me know how it looks like.

Comment: looks like someone already made an app... http://www.igeeksblog.com/turn-iphone-into-remote-control-for-smart-tv/. Just google for samsung specific apps and you will get a lot of results. Do you want an API specifically or do you just want the app?

Comment: @CaptJak I know that there are apps on the market that allows to remote control TVs. I would like to know how I can implement that feature myself, thus I am asking if there is any official (or nonofficial) API or SDK I could use.

Comment: @Darrarski, Any luck finding an API or SDK?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that.

You will need to download the [Samsung SmartTV SDK](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Devtools/SdkDownload). The [Development Guide](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/) has all the instructions to create a Javascript application with Websockets (or even to let you create a [C/C++ TCP Socket](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/?FolderName=d25&FileName=index.html) app)

Comment: Well but how do you connect to the tv

Comment: Either through websockets or TCP.

Comment: @Hbas Links are not working anymore, they open the developer's home page.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if that's possible anymore, it has been years since I last programmed with the Samsung TV. You can look into [the Smart View SDK](https://developer.samsung.com/tv/develop/extension-libraries/smart-view-sdk/getting-started/) and see if it helps